# Azure PostgreSql ODBC connection error SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer (0x00002746/10054)

Tags: postgresql, azure-database-postgresql

I am trying to create a odbc connection for a Azure PostgreSQL db. Currently getting the error **SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer (0x00002746/10054)**. When I disable **Enforce SSL Connection**, on the Azure PostgreSQL the connection is successful.

The following is the details of the ODBC setup

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are getting SSL connection issue while creating an ODBC connection for Azure PostgreSQL DB. I would suggest verifying and adding the required vnet and firewall rules. Then retry connecting to the server when SSL is enabled. This can help mitigate the issue.